# Javascript Stopwatch in Raphael Library won't continuously tick

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, raphael, stopwatch, ticker

I'm quite new to Java and am making a watch as part of my Uni course. Ive made a ticker on a small face that i want to tick round per second operated by clicking to buttons, however the hand only moves when i click it and won't carry on. Here is my code:

```
sbutton1.click(function(){
stoshand.animate({transform: [ 'r',tick,250,345]})
tick=tick+6;
}, 500);
sbutton2.click(function(){
stoshand.stop();
});
```

Can anyone help as to why it won't continuously tick after one click, rather than me having to continuously tick. THANKS :)

Comment: You don't have any form of loop or repeat in there. I would get the Date as a function, and rotate the minutes depending upon mins, maybe with a bounce easing, pop it in a setInterval/setTimeout/setAnimation frame type callback.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you getting started with coding. It's with-out animation but it shows how you can do the clock tick.

Just add your drawing code to the watch callback and it will update it every second.

See the demo below and it's also here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/5z8f0yqh/).

```js
var interval;

var watch = function() {
    $watch = $('#watch');
    $watch.html(new Date());
};

$('#startCounter').click(function() {
    watch(); //call manually to display time now;
    interval = setInterval(watch, 1000);    
});

$('#stopCounter').click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="startCounter" href="#">start</a>
<a id="stopCounter" href="#">stop</a>

<div id="watch"></div>
```